# How to convert an angular app to a npm package or a Library?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package

I have an angular app. It fetches photos and videos from the server and shows them as a slide(one by one). Now i need to integrate this feature into another app. Is there any way to convert the angular app to a library or a package? So, i can simply install the package using npm i.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an Angular library you can push it to NPM but this works only with other angular apps. https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Another options is to user Angular Elements. This will create some web components. You can integrate the webcomponents in any HTML/JS webpage https://angular.io/guide/elements

the last option I see it tho use iFrames.